# How to decide which values will appear on y axis according to selection of perticular date in x-axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In [this chart](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-time-series) how we can decide that the given value of y-axis is of which particular date of x-axis.

```
 series: [{
                type: 'area',
                name: 'USD to EUR',
                pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
                pointStart: Date.UTC(2006, 0, 01),
                data: [
                    0.8446, 0.8445, 0.8444, 0.8451,    0.8418, 0.8264,    0.8258, 0.8232,    0.8233, 0.8258,
                    0.8283, 0.8278, 0.8256, 0.8292,    0.8239, 0.8239,    0.8245, 0.8265,    0.8261, 0.8269,
                    0.8273, 0.8244, 0.8244, 0.8172,    0.8139, 0.8146,    0.8164, 0.82,    0.8269, 0.8269,
                    0.8269, 0.8258, 0.8247, 0.8286,    0.8289, 0.8316,    0.832, 0.8333,    0.8352, 0.8357,
                    0.8355, 0.8354, 0.8403, 0.8403,    0.8406, 0.8403,    0.8396, 0.8418,    0.8409, 0.8384,
                    0.8386, 0.8372, 0.839, 0.84, 0.8389, 0.84, 0.8423, 0.8423, 0.8435, 0.8422,
                    0.838, 0.8373, 0.8316, 0.8303,    0.8303, 0.8302,    0.8369, 0.84, 0.8385, 0.84,
                    0.8401, 0.8402, 0.8381, 0.8351,    0.8314, 0.8273,    0.8213, 0.8207,    0.8207, 0.8215,
                    0.8242, 0.8273, 0.8301, 0.8346,    0.8312, 0.8312,    0.8312, 0.8306,    0.8327, 0.8282,
                    0.824, 0.8255, 0.8256, 0.8273, 0.8209, 0.8151, 0.8149, 0.8213, 0.8273, 0.8273,
                    0.8261, 0.8252, 0.824, 0.8262, 0.8258, 0.8261, 0.826, 0.8199, 0.8153, 0.8097,
                    0.8101, 0.8119, 0.8107, 0.8105,    0.8084, 0.8069,    0.8047, 0.8023,    0.7965, 0.7919,
                    0.7921, 0.7922, 0.7934, 0.7918,    0.7915, 0.787, 0.7861, 0.7861, 0.7853, 0.7867,
                    0.7827, 0.7834, 0.7766, 0.7751, 0.7739, 0.7767, 0.7802, 0.7788, 0.7828, 0.7816,
                    0.7829, 0.783, 0.7829, 0.7781, 0.7811, 0.7831, 0.7826, 0.7855, 0.7855, 0.7845,
                    0.7798, 0.7777, 0.7822, 0.7785, 0.7744, 0.7743, 0.7726, 0.7766, 0.7806, 0.785,
                    0.7907, 0.7912, 0.7913, 0.7931, 0.7952, 0.7951, 0.7928, 0.791, 0.7913, 0.7912,
                    0.7941, 0.7953, 0.7921, 0.7919, 0.7968, 0.7999, 0.7999, 0.7974, 0.7942, 0.796,
                    0.7969, 0.7862, 0.7821, 0.7821, 0.7821, 0.7811, 0.7833, 0.7849, 0.7819, 0.7809,
                    0.7809, 0.7827, 0.7848, 0.785, 0.7873, 0.7894, 0.7907, 0.7909, 0.7947, 0.7987,
                    0.799, 0.7927, 0.79, 0.7878, 0.7878, 0.7907, 0.7922, 0.7937, 0.786, 0.787,
                    0.7838, 0.7838, 0.7837, 0.7836, 0.7806, 0.7825, 0.7798, 0.777, 0.777, 0.7772,
                    0.7793, 0.7788, 0.7785, 0.7832, 0.7865, 0.7865, 0.7853, 0.7847, 0.7809, 0.778,
                    0.7799, 0.78, 0.7801, 0.7765, 0.7785, 0.7811, 0.782, 0.7835, 0.7845, 0.7844,
                    0.782, 0.7811, 0.7795, 0.7794, 0.7806, 0.7794, 0.7794, 0.7778, 0.7793, 0.7808,
                    0.7824, 0.787, 0.7894, 0.7893, 0.7882, 0.7871, 0.7882, 0.7871, 0.7878, 0.79,
                    0.7901, 0.7898, 0.7879, 0.7886, 0.7858, 0.7814, 0.7825, 0.7826, 0.7826, 0.786,
                    0.7878, 0.7868, 0.7883, 0.7893, 0.7892, 0.7876, 0.785, 0.787, 0.7873, 0.7901,
                    0.7936, 0.7939, 0.7938, 0.7956, 0.7975, 0.7978, 0.7972, 0.7995, 0.7995, 0.7994,
                    0.7976, 0.7977, 0.796, 0.7922, 0.7928, 0.7929, 0.7948, 0.797, 0.7953, 0.7907,
                    0.7872, 0.7852, 0.7852, 0.786, 0.7862, 0.7836, 0.7837, 0.784, 0.7867, 0.7867,
                    0.7869, 0.7837, 0.7827, 0.7825, 0.7779, 0.7791, 0.779, 0.7787, 0.78, 0.7807,
                    0.7803, 0.7817, 0.7799, 0.7799, 0.7795, 0.7801, 0.7765, 0.7725, 0.7683, 0.7641,
                    0.7639, 0.7616, 0.7608, 0.759, 0.7582, 0.7539, 0.75, 0.75, 0.7507, 0.7505,
                    0.7516, 0.7522, 0.7531, 0.7577, 0.7577, 0.7582, 0.755, 0.7542, 0.7576, 0.7616,
                    0.7648, 0.7648, 0.7641, 0.7614, 0.757, 0.7587, 0.7588, 0.762, 0.762, 0.7617,
                    0.7618, 0.7615, 0.7612, 0.7596, 0.758, 0.758, 0.758, 0.7547, 0.7549, 0.7613,
                    0.7655, 0.7693, 0.7694, 0.7688, 0.7678, 0.7708, 0.7727, 0.7749, 0.7741, 0.7741,
                    0.7732, 0.7727, 0.7737, 0.7724, 0.7712, 0.772, 0.7721, 0.7717, 0.7704, 0.769,
                    0.7711, 0.774, 0.7745, 0.7745, 0.774, 0.7716, 0.7713, 0.7678, 0.7688, 0.7718,
                    0.7718, 0.7728, 0.7729, 0.7698, 0.7685, 0.7681, 0.769, 0.769, 0.7698, 0.7699,
                    0.7651, 0.7613, 0.7616, 0.7614, 0.7614, 0.7607, 0.7602, 0.7611, 0.7622, 0.7615,
                    0.7598, 0.7598, 0.7592, 0.7573, 0.7566, 0.7567, 0.7591, 0.7582, 0.7585, 0.7613,
                    0.7631, 0.7615, 0.76, 0.7613, 0.7627, 0.7627, 0.7608, 0.7583, 0.7575, 0.7562,
                    0.752, 0.7512, 0.7512, 0.7517, 0.752, 0.7511, 0.748, 0.7509, 0.7531, 0.7531,
                    0.7527, 0.7498, 0.7493, 0.7504, 0.75, 0.7491, 0.7491, 0.7485, 0.7484, 0.7492,
                    0.7471, 0.7459, 0.7477, 0.7477, 0.7483, 0.7458, 0.7448, 0.743, 0.7399, 0.7395,
                    0.7395, 0.7378, 0.7382, 0.7362, 0.7355, 0.7348, 0.7361, 0.7361, 0.7365, 0.7362,
                    0.7331, 0.7339, 0.7344, 0.7327, 0.7327, 0.7336, 0.7333, 0.7359, 0.7359, 0.7372,
                    0.736, 0.736, 0.735, 0.7365, 0.7384, 0.7395, 0.7413, 0.7397, 0.7396, 0.7385,
                    0.7378, 0.7366, 0.74, 0.7411, 0.7406, 0.7405, 0.7414, 0.7431, 0.7431, 0.7438,
                    0.7443, 0.7443, 0.7443, 0.7434, 0.7429, 0.7442, 0.744, 0.7439, 0.7437, 0.7437,
                    0.7429, 0.7403, 0.7399, 0.7418, 0.7468, 0.748, 0.748, 0.749, 0.7494, 0.7522,
                    0.7515, 0.7502, 0.7472, 0.7472, 0.7462, 0.7455, 0.7449, 0.7467, 0.7458, 0.7427,
                    0.7427, 0.743, 0.7429, 0.744, 0.743, 0.7422, 0.7388, 0.7388, 0.7369, 0.7345,
                    0.7345, 0.7345, 0.7352, 0.7341, 0.7341, 0.734, 0.7324, 0.7272, 0.7264, 0.7255,
                    0.7258, 0.7258, 0.7256, 0.7257, 0.7247, 0.7243, 0.7244, 0.7235, 0.7235, 0.7235,
                    0.7235, 0.7262, 0.7288, 0.7301, 0.7337, 0.7337, 0.7324, 0.7297, 0.7317, 0.7315,
                    0.7288, 0.7263, 0.7263, 0.7242, 0.7253, 0.7264, 0.727, 0.7312, 0.7305, 0.7305,
                    0.7318, 0.7358, 0.7409, 0.7454, 0.7437, 0.7424, 0.7424, 0.7415, 0.7419, 0.7414,
                    0.7377, 0.7355, 0.7315, 0.7315, 0.732, 0.7332, 0.7346, 0.7328, 0.7323, 0.734,
                    0.734, 0.7336, 0.7351, 0.7346, 0.7321, 0.7294, 0.7266, 0.7266, 0.7254, 0.7242,
                    0.7213, 0.7197, 0.7209, 0.721, 0.721, 0.721, 0.7209, 0.7159, 0.7133, 0.7105,
                    0.7099, 0.7099, 0.7093, 0.7093, 0.7076, 0.707, 0.7049, 0.7012, 0.7011, 0.7019,
                    0.7046, 0.7063, 0.7089, 0.7077, 0.7077, 0.7077, 0.7091, 0.7118, 0.7079, 0.7053,
                    0.705, 0.7055, 0.7055, 0.7045, 0.7051, 0.7051, 0.7017, 0.7, 0.6995, 0.6994,
                    0.7014, 0.7036, 0.7021, 0.7002, 0.6967, 0.695, 0.695, 0.6939, 0.694, 0.6922,
                    0.6919, 0.6914, 0.6894, 0.6891, 0.6904, 0.689, 0.6834, 0.6823, 0.6807, 0.6815,
                    0.6815, 0.6847, 0.6859, 0.6822, 0.6827, 0.6837, 0.6823, 0.6822, 0.6822, 0.6792,
                    0.6746, 0.6735, 0.6731, 0.6742, 0.6744, 0.6739, 0.6731, 0.6761, 0.6761, 0.6785,
                    0.6818, 0.6836, 0.6823, 0.6805, 0.6793, 0.6849, 0.6833, 0.6825, 0.6825, 0.6816,
                    0.6799, 0.6813, 0.6809, 0.6868, 0.6933, 0.6933, 0.6945, 0.6944, 0.6946, 0.6964,
                    0.6965, 0.6956, 0.6956, 0.695, 0.6948, 0.6928, 0.6887, 0.6824, 0.6794, 0.6794,
                    0.6803, 0.6855, 0.6824, 0.6791, 0.6783, 0.6785, 0.6785, 0.6797, 0.68, 0.6803,
                    0.6805, 0.676, 0.677, 0.677, 0.6736, 0.6726, 0.6764, 0.6821, 0.6831, 0.6842,
                    0.6842, 0.6887, 0.6903, 0.6848, 0.6824, 0.6788, 0.6814, 0.6814, 0.6797, 0.6769,
                    0.6765, 0.6733, 0.6729, 0.6758, 0.6758, 0.675, 0.678, 0.6833, 0.6856, 0.6903,
                    0.6896, 0.6896, 0.6882, 0.6879, 0.6862, 0.6852, 0.6823, 0.6813, 0.6813, 0.6822,
                    0.6802, 0.6802, 0.6784, 0.6748, 0.6747, 0.6747, 0.6748, 0.6733, 0.665, 0.6611,
                    0.6583, 0.659, 0.659, 0.6581, 0.6578, 0.6574, 0.6532, 0.6502, 0.6514, 0.6514,
                    0.6507, 0.651, 0.6489, 0.6424, 0.6406, 0.6382, 0.6382, 0.6341, 0.6344, 0.6378,
                    0.6439, 0.6478, 0.6481, 0.6481, 0.6494, 0.6438, 0.6377, 0.6329, 0.6336, 0.6333,
                    0.6333, 0.633, 0.6371, 0.6403, 0.6396, 0.6364, 0.6356, 0.6356, 0.6368, 0.6357,
                    0.6354, 0.632, 0.6332, 0.6328, 0.6331, 0.6342, 0.6321, 0.6302, 0.6278, 0.6308,
                    0.6324, 0.6324, 0.6307, 0.6277, 0.6269, 0.6335, 0.6392, 0.64, 0.6401, 0.6396,
                    0.6407, 0.6423, 0.6429, 0.6472, 0.6485, 0.6486, 0.6467, 0.6444, 0.6467, 0.6509,
                    0.6478, 0.6461, 0.6461, 0.6468, 0.6449, 0.647, 0.6461, 0.6452, 0.6422, 0.6422,
                    0.6425, 0.6414, 0.6366, 0.6346, 0.635, 0.6346, 0.6346, 0.6343, 0.6346, 0.6379,
                    0.6416, 0.6442, 0.6431, 0.6431, 0.6435, 0.644, 0.6473, 0.6469, 0.6386, 0.6356,
                    0.634, 0.6346, 0.643, 0.6452, 0.6467, 0.6506, 0.6504, 0.6503, 0.6481, 0.6451,
                    0.645, 0.6441, 0.6414, 0.6409, 0.6409, 0.6428, 0.6431, 0.6418, 0.6371, 0.6349,
                    0.6333, 0.6334, 0.6338, 0.6342, 0.632, 0.6318, 0.637, 0.6368, 0.6368, 0.6383,
                    0.6371, 0.6371, 0.6355, 0.632, 0.6277, 0.6276, 0.6291, 0.6274, 0.6293, 0.6311,
                    0.631, 0.6312, 0.6312, 0.6304, 0.6294, 0.6348, 0.6378, 0.6368, 0.6368, 0.6368,
                    0.636, 0.637, 0.6418, 0.6411, 0.6435, 0.6427, 0.6427, 0.6419, 0.6446, 0.6468,
                    0.6487, 0.6594, 0.6666, 0.6666, 0.6678, 0.6712, 0.6705, 0.6718, 0.6784, 0.6811,
                    0.6811, 0.6794, 0.6804, 0.6781, 0.6756, 0.6735, 0.6763, 0.6762, 0.6777, 0.6815,
                    0.6802, 0.678, 0.6796, 0.6817, 0.6817, 0.6832, 0.6877, 0.6912, 0.6914, 0.7009,
                    0.7012, 0.701, 0.7005, 0.7076, 0.7087, 0.717, 0.7105, 0.7031, 0.7029, 0.7006,
                    0.7035, 0.7045, 0.6956, 0.6988, 0.6915, 0.6914, 0.6859, 0.6778, 0.6815, 0.6815,
                    0.6843, 0.6846, 0.6846, 0.6923, 0.6997, 0.7098, 0.7188, 0.7232, 0.7262, 0.7266,
                    0.7359, 0.7368, 0.7337, 0.7317, 0.7387, 0.7467, 0.7461, 0.7366, 0.7319, 0.7361,
                    0.7437, 0.7432, 0.7461, 0.7461, 0.7454, 0.7549, 0.7742, 0.7801, 0.7903, 0.7876,
                    0.7928, 0.7991, 0.8007, 0.7823, 0.7661, 0.785, 0.7863, 0.7862, 0.7821, 0.7858,
                    0.7731, 0.7779, 0.7844, 0.7866, 0.7864, 0.7788, 0.7875, 0.7971, 0.8004, 0.7857,
                    0.7932, 0.7938, 0.7927, 0.7918, 0.7919, 0.7989, 0.7988, 0.7949, 0.7948, 0.7882,
                    0.7745, 0.771, 0.775, 0.7791, 0.7882, 0.7882, 0.7899, 0.7905, 0.7889, 0.7879,
                    0.7855, 0.7866, 0.7865, 0.7795, 0.7758, 0.7717, 0.761, 0.7497, 0.7471, 0.7473,
                    0.7407, 0.7288, 0.7074, 0.6927, 0.7083, 0.7191, 0.719, 0.7153, 0.7156, 0.7158,
                    0.714, 0.7119, 0.7129, 0.7129, 0.7049, 0.7095
                ]
            }]
```

Answer (score 0):

By using click event, you can retrieve the clicked point and see its x and y values.

```
plotOptions: {
             area: {         
                    events: {
                             click: function(event) {
                             alert(event.point.x + ' -> ' + event.point.y);
                                                    }
                             }
                    }
              }
```

> http://jsfiddle.net/GbE3s/2/

Comment: no may be asked this query in wrong sense, what i want to know is specified the time interval, then for e.x i put date in x-axies and net income on y-axies if for and particular day their is no transaction happen then i want to put it as blank or i don't want to display value for that particular date. and in the given chart they specified the value for each day so how can i speek the value for particular day or how can i put it blank.. Ex.on x-axies 21-01-2013 to 25-01-2013 i only want to display the value of 3 days 21-22-23 and don't want blank on y axies for 24 and 25, then how can i do it?

Comment: Hmm I haven't used highchart in such a way. But it seems to me pointInterval is for one day, and chart starts from 1/01/2006 and first point 0.8446 is for that day, the second point 0.8445 is for next day (02/01/2006) and it goes like that. So for your particular date, you should add a 0 to the data array according to the index of your date. For example if you want to zero out 10/01/2006 then you replace the 10th value in the array with zero. Here is an example where the second day is zero, just zoom in and see it for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/tgF9K/

Comment: That is also acceptable and i am kind of aware with it but i want a specific value because i want to merge this http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic kind of structure in my chart, so if 1 company may not have transaction on 1 particular day but the other has possible so if i put 0 then it will not work.

Comment: Why wouldn't it work, for one series you will give 0, but for the other series who has transactions you will give the amount of the transaction and it would work. As long as you keep the number of values for all series on the chart same there won't be any problem I guess.